# Query to fetch records only form previous half hour with time stamp in unix epoch format

Tags: sql, oracle, epoch, date-arithmetic

I want `SQL` query to `fetch/select` records which are taken only from previous half an hour only. For example if my scheduler ran at 2 pm, and then again in 2:30, during the 2:30 run it should  only pick rows from between 2pm and 2:30pm and not earlier, using the column `created_timestamp` which stores the time as unix epoch format eg:

```
|created_timestamp|
|1497355750350    |
|1497506182344    |
```

Comment: the created_timestamp column is in number format

Comment: I'm pretty sure your question is a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555814/convert-oracles-timestamp-to-seconds-from-epoch).

Answer (score 2):

We can do arithmetic with Oracle dates. Subtracting one date from another gives the interval as a fractional number. Multiplying by 86400 gives us the number of seconds. So this is the current unix expoch:

```
(sysdate - date '1970-01-01') * 86400
```

This means your query will be something like

```
select * from your_table
where created_timestamp >= (:last_run_time - date '1970-01-01') * 86400
```

The trick is that your scheduler needs to pass in the  time of the *previous* run -  `last_run_time` - to pick up all the records which have been added since then.

Answer (score 0):

You can do Flashback query

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
AS OF TIMESTAMP (SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '30' MINUTE);
```

Comment: The target column is a Unix epoch timestamp. So its contents may be different from the database system timestamp

Comment: @APC Does it require epoch column? It won't work without it?

Comment: The question is asking to get a set of records based on the contents of a column. Given that we don't know how or when `created_timestamp` is populated we cannot be certain that there is an exact correspondence with the database system timestamp. So I think your solution could produce a different result set from the one the OP requires. Apart from anything else, consider what would happen if the job is delayed by five minutes.

Comment: With all respect to your expertise, still I am not convinced. OP asks how to get records taken certain amount of time before. That's main concern. IMHO, we may get rid of `created_timestamp` in general, would work as desired. So I can consider `created_timestamp` as part of implementation, not requirement. I did not quite understand your question in regards to delay, please clarify.

Comment: If there's some problem with the job and it starts at 2:35 instead of 2;30, your query will only pick up records written to the database on or after 2:05. Records written between 2.00 and 2.04 will be lost. That strikes me as highly undesirable, as processing all the records is surely a requirement.

Comment: Query will pick up snapshots as of 30 minutes intervals, isn't?

Comment: Yes but that is not the same as picking up all the records added since the last time the job ran. I think picking up all the records is the real requirement. You are free to disagree. Only the OP knows for sure and they seem to have lost interest in this thread.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanations.